# Why I can't use "dlsym" to get function pointer in ios, but it works well on Android?

Tags: c++, ios, posix

The following is my code:

```
char* libPath = "libSum.dylib";
char* func_name = "_sum";

void *libHandle = dlopen(libPath, 2);
if(libHandle != NULL){
    int (*sum)(int, int) = dlsym(libHandle, func_name);
    if(sum != NULL){
         NSLog(@"%d", sum(5, 6));
    }
}
```

libSum.dylib source code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport){
    int __stdcall sum(int x, int y){
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

1. I can get a value(not null) by ***dlopen***;
2. I use "_sum" as entryPoint, because I get the name of "sum" by *commandline: nm -g libSum.dylib*.
   But "sum" and "_sum" are both *NULL*.
3. I don't know why dlsym return a zero value;

These interface(dlopen, dlsym) did good in Android.

Comment: There is a `dlerror` function for such problems.

Comment: Thanks, I try it. It tells me that "dlsym symbol not found.". I try nm -g to get symbol, but also symbol not found. I dont know where is wrong.

Comment: Try `nm -D` too. (Please insert the command that creates the shared object.)

Comment: Oh my god, I found it's different between "c" and "c++" symbol of dynamic library. 
eg. the same function name is different in "c" and "c++" dynamic library. That's why c  not suppoorted overload, c++ could. Thanks man.

Comment: That should have been covered by `extern "C"`